# Creating a list of dates within WITH clause - GG Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to to create a list of every first day of every month starting from 2021-01-01 for the next 24 months.

With normal SQL, it has worked with these following codes that I had found online:

```
with mnt as (
  select 1 as n, convert(date,'20210101',112) as d
  union all
  select n + 1, dateadd(month,1,d)
  from mnt
  where n < 24
)
select d from mnt
```

(You can also see it in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d9pqYoBA))

However, when I tried that same logic on BigQuery it did not work, as the error stated that: *Table "mnt" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)*

```
with mnt as (
  select 1 as n, CAST('2021-07-01' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d
  union all
  select n+1, date_add(CAST('2021-07-01' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  from mnt
  where n < 24
)

select d as salesmonth from mnt
```

[See the code on BigQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EadNX.png)

I also tried looping on Big Query

```
declare x DATE DEFAULT "2021-07-01";

REPEAT 
  Set x = date_add(x, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
  SELECT x;
  until x > CAST('2023-07-01' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
END REPEAT;
```

but the results do not come out in tabular form, nor I know how to put them within a WITH clause.

Does anyone know how to fix this and adapt the above SQL query in Big Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query using [**WITH RECURSIVE**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#recursive_keyword) will work in your case.

```sql
with recursive mnt as (
  select 1 as n, DATE '2021-01-01' as d
  union all
  select n + 1, date_add(d, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  from mnt
  where n < 24
)
select d as salesmonth from mnt;
```

But in BigQuery [**GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY()**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array) is more handy than  recursive approach.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-01-01', '2022-12-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) salesmonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below option

```
select date_add('2021-01-01', interval i month)
from unnest(generate_array(0, 23)) i
```